# Will the new Boeing NMA be 'more electric' than the current B787?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, boeing-787, bleed-air

I understand that the B787 is the 'most electric' aircraft to date, however there have been many issues with the plane, and I'm interested in knowing if the latest [Boeing New Midsize Aircraft (NMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_New_Midsize_Airplane) - possibly the B797 - will still use the same 'more electric aircraft' architecture as a result.

Specifically, are there any details/guesses on the following:

1. If the electrical power generation capacity of the Boeing NMA will be lower/higher than the B787
2. If the Boeing NMA will 'revert' back to traditional bleed-air engine systems.
3. If the Boeing NMA will use more or less electric components (such as in actuation systems) than the B787.

Any help on any one of the questions would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have they announced the 797? It would help to know what plane we're talking about - the NMA or something else.

Comment: Oops sorry I meant the new Boeing NMA

Comment: Do you have a reference to the 'many issues with the plane', the B787?

Comment: As far as I know none of the variable frequency generators, the electrical pressurization, or electrical actuators were issues to the contrary they gave full satisfaction and reduced fuel consumption. The issues were with the lithium batteries, the single piece composite body, the fuel leaks, and logistic provisions from numerous manufacturers outside the group. So there is no reason to return to conventional bleed, non electrical actuators, constant frequency generators etc. Of course the lithium batteries are a problem, but now in case of fire it is limited to a containment.